xrandr, autorandr does not work with 3 monitors
just switched from manjaro to eos i3wm, autorandr -c does nothing when connected to 3 monitors but it does work with 2 monitors and there are no error messages. swapping display cables did not make any change.
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti Lite Hash Rate
what i do ...
xrandr --output DP-0 --primary
xrandr --output DP-2 --mode 1920x1080
xrandr --output DP-2 --pos 0x0
xrandr --output DP-2 --rotate inverted
xrandr --output DP-5 --mode 1920x1080
xrandr --output DP-5 --below DP-2
xrandr --output DP-0 --mode 1920x1080
xrandr --output DP-0 --right-of DP-5

autorandr --save primary --force
autorandr -c

primary (detected) (current)
Config already loaded

reboot and
$ autorandr -c
primary

$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 8960 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 connected 2560x1440+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440    144.00*+ 120.00    59.95    59.95  
   1920x1080    119.88    60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 698mm x 393mm
   2560x1440     75.00*+  59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 connected 3840x2160+5120+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     29.97*+  25.00    23.98  
   1920x1080    119.98   119.88   100.00    99.91    60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1440x900     119.85  
   1280x1024    119.96    75.02    60.02  
   1280x960     100.00  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1024x768     119.99    75.03    60.00  
   800x600      119.97   100.00    75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480      120.01    75.00    59.94    59.93


I noticed my .xsession_errors outputs could not find a file named "~/.screenlayout/monitor.sh". created .screenlayouts/monitor.sh since it did not exist then added my xrandr commands to it and added execute permission to monitor.sh, reboot and monitor.sh is executed on start.
mkdir -p ~/.screenlayout/monitor.sh

#!/bin/bash    
xrandr --output DP-2 --mode 1920x1080 --rotate inverted --pos 960x0
xrandr --output DP-5 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x1080
xrandr --output DP-0 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --right-of DP-5

chmod +x monitor.sh

